# Index out of range exception using DispatchQueue

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have the following code which shows a list of quizzes in a `UITableView.` The problem is that to show the images I call my method `prepareImages` and I get an index out of range exception when filling the cells in `tableView` function because it appears that the `quizzesImages` array is empty (`print(self.quizzesImages.count)` shows `0`), I know it has something to do with how I put the threads to work but I don't see where I am going wrong.

```
import UIKit
 // Estructura del JSON que devuelve la URL
struct ResponseObject : Codable {
let quizzes : [Quiz]?
let pageno : Int?
    let nextUrl : String?
}

class QuizzesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

// Aquí se guardan los quizzes cargados de la URL
var totalQuizzes = [Quiz]()
var quizzesImages = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 90.0
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    downloadQuizzes()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func prepareImages(){
    for i in 0...self.totalQuizzes.count-1{

        let imageUrlString = self.totalQuizzes[i].attachment?.url
        let imageUrl:URL = URL(string: imageUrlString!)!
        print(imageUrl)

        // Start background thread so that image loading does not make app unresponsive
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            let imageData:NSData = NSData(contentsOf: imageUrl)!

            // When from background thread, UI needs to be updated on main_queue
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
                print("hola")
                self.quizzesImages.append(image!)
            }
        }
    }

}

func downloadQuizzes(){
    let QUIZZES_URL = "https://quiz2019.herokuapp.com/api/quizzes?token=945d3bf7d4c709d69940"
    if let url = URL(string: QUIZZES_URL){
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "download quizzes queue")
        queue.async {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
            }
            defer{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                }
            }
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url, options: .alwaysMapped)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do{
                let response = try decoder.decode(ResponseObject.self, from: data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if (response.quizzes!.count != 0){
                        self.totalQuizzes.append(contentsOf: response.quizzes!)
                        self.prepareImages()
                        print(self.totalQuizzes.count)
                        print(self.quizzesImages.count)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return totalQuizzes.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Quiz", for: indexPath) as! QuizTableViewCell

    let quiz = totalQuizzes[indexPath.row]
    let images = quizzesImages[indexPath.row]
    cell.authorLabel?.text = quiz.author?.username
    cell.quizLabel?.text = quiz.question
    cell.quizImage?.image = images
    return cell
}}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You check if `esponse.quizzes!.count != 0` is true? Try print `response.quizzes`

Comment: @Augusto yes, it is, totalQuizzes has 10 elements after running so the code below gets executed

Comment: @martingoldthen can you give what is inside Quiz

Comment: @martingoldthen give the entity class Defination of Quiz so can run and see it

Comment: post `response.quizzes` content.

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar     This is Quiz.swift file                                                                          `import Foundation

struct Quiz : Codable {
    let id : Int?
    let question : String?
    let author : Author?
    let attachment : Attachment?
    let favourite : Bool?
    let tips : [String]?
    
    struct Author: Codable {
        let id: Int?
        let isAdmin : Bool?
        let username : String?
    }
    
    struct Attachment : Codable {
        let filename : String?
        let mime : String?
        let url : String?
    }
    
}`

Comment: @Augusto Optional([QuizMartin.Quiz(id: Optional(3), question: Optional("Capital of Spain"), author: nil, attachment: Optional(QuizMartin.Quiz.Attachment(filename: Optional("Unknown.jpeg"), mime: Optional("image/jpeg"), url: Optional("https://res.cloudinary.com/core-upm/image/upload/v1540376964/core/quiz2018/attachments/xpxtyowtxrfuhhscpj4n.jpg"))), favourite: Optional(false), tips: Optional(["Acaba en d", "En el centro del pais", "M*****"])),...... and so on with another 9 objects

Comment: @martingoldthen any ways got it form the url response

Comment: @martingoldthen can u tell us exact where u get exception?

Comment: @martingoldthen can you tell us where u get exception plz

Comment: @martingoldthen See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this screen shot form my playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usC2k.jpg)

I tried to run your code in playground and managed to get it work with some changes please see the following.

> **Note**

To make it run in playground i have to make some assumptions just replace your core logic with my one.

Happy Coding

```
import UIKit
// Estructura del JSON que devuelve la URL

struct ResponseObject: Codable {
    let quizzes: [Quiz]?
    let pageno: Int?
    let nextURL: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case quizzes, pageno
        case nextURL = "nextUrl"
    }
}

struct Quiz: Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let question: String?
    let author: Author?
    let attachment: Attachment?
    let favourite: Bool?
    let tips: [String]?
}

struct Attachment: Codable {
    let filename: String?
    let mime: MIME?
    let url: String?
}

enum MIME: String, Codable {
    case imageJPEG = "image/jpeg"
}

struct Author: Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let isAdmin: Bool?
    let username: String?
}


class QuizzesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // Aquí se guardan los quizzes cargados de la URL
    var totalQuizzes = [Quiz]()
    var quizzesImages = [UIImage]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.rowHeight = 90.0
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Quiz")
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        downloadQuizzes()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func prepareImages(){
        print("in prepare images")
        // Start background thread so that image loading does not make app unresponsive
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            for i in 0...self.totalQuizzes.count-1 {

                let imageUrlString = self.totalQuizzes[i].attachment?.url
                let imageUrl:URL = URL(string: imageUrlString!)!
                print(imageUrl)

            let imageData:NSData = NSData(contentsOf: imageUrl)!
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
            print("hola \(i)")
            self.quizzesImages.append(image!)
            print(self.quizzesImages.count)
            // When from background thread, UI needs to be updated on main_queue
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(self.quizzesImages.count)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            }
        }
    }

    func downloadQuizzes(){
        let QUIZZES_URL = "https://quiz2019.herokuapp.com/api/quizzes?token=945d3bf7d4c709d69940"
        if let url = URL(string: QUIZZES_URL){
            let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "download quizzes queue")
            queue.async {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
                }
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url, options: .alwaysMapped)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do{
                    let response = try decoder.decode(ResponseObject.self, from: data!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if (response.quizzes!.count != 0){
                            self.totalQuizzes.append(contentsOf: response.quizzes!)
                            self.prepareImages()
                            print(self.totalQuizzes.count)
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        print("num of rows \(totalQuizzes.count)")
        return totalQuizzes.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("in cellForRowAt \(indexPath.row)")
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Quiz")!
        let quiz = totalQuizzes[indexPath.row]
        let images = quizzesImages[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(quiz.author?.username) \(quiz.question)"
        cell.imageView?.image = images
        return cell
    }}
```

Comment: This worked, I had to `self.tableView.reloadData()` on `prepareImages`. Thank you very much

Comment: Yes and that too after ending the for loop

Comment: Feel free to upvote also if it helped. Once Again Happy coding

Comment: I did, but my reputation is under 15 and it doesn't show, sorry

Comment: No Worries Happy Coding. Keep Learning

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't say what line the exception is happening on, my best guess is that it's happening on this line.

```
let images = quizzesImages[indexPath.row]
```

The issue is in `downloadQuizzes`. In there you call `prepareImages` then a couple lines later call `reloadData`. Since `prepareImages` does an async task, it isn't blocking `downloadQuizzes` from finishing running. This causes `reloadData` to be called before the async part of `prepareImages` is finished.

You'll need to make sure `prepareImages` is finished running before calling `reloadData`.

Another option is to use a library like Kingfisher that will only download the images when they need to be displayed in a cell rather then downloading them all and slowing down showing the table.

---

Additional Note:

You shouldn't be using `Data(contentsOf:)` to load remote content, `URLSession` is the correct option for it.

Comment: Yes! Taking out all the async tasks in `prepareImages` makes it work! How would I do it so `reloadData` isn't called until `prepareImages` is done? Thank you so much!